# How to remove/rename definition from current scope?

Tags: scala, import, scope

How could I rename definition from the current scope? The encouraging example:

```
package fails {
  trait A
  object Inner {
    import A => AA // error here
    trait B
    trait A extends AA with B
  }
}
```

The code with separate packages works but it looks like boilerplate:

```
package works {
  package boilerplate {
    trait A
  }
  import boilerplate._

  object Inner {
    import boilerplate.{A => AA}
    trait B
    trait A extends AA with B
  }
}
```

How could it be written elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

Make a slight adjustment:

```
package works {
  trait A
  object Inner {
    import works.{A => AA}
    trait B
    trait A extends AA with B
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify full package path, which defeats purpose of relative imports. I could not just rename package `works` to package `worksexcellently`. It would force me to change inter-modules interaction besides outer references.